# Uncaught TypeError using MathJax in a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, mathjax, firefox-addon-webextensions, web-extension

I am trying to write a browser extension for Firefox and want to use MathJax to show Mathematics in WhatsApp Web using Tex Notation. Whenever I try to load MathJax though, I get the following error:

[The Error Code displayed in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BV7or.png)

This is the code that I have so far to inject MathJax into the website:

```js
  MathJax = {
    tex: {
      inlineMath:[['$', '$'],['\\(','\\)']]
    }
  }
  

const script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript'
script.src = 'moz-extension://43ecc479-a843-4102-b4dc-afee633fe04a/MathJax/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

The Script source is the locally saved MathJax Version. I can not use a CDN because of the same origin policy.

I tried to use a different js File in MathJax, like the tex-chtml.js file but got the same error.

Comment: You need to declare `web_accessible_resources` and use browser.runtime.getURL('MathJax/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js') instead of the full URL.